# Typescript: different return type based on parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a class method that looks like this:

```
  handleTab<B extends boolean = false>(getIndex?: B): B extends true ? number : string {
    return getIndex ? 1 : '';
  }
```

I get an error:
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'B extends true ? number : string'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'B extends true ? number : string'

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: This is essentially a missing feature in TS, see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) and/or [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  The compiler doesn't know how to determine what values are assignable to a generic conditional type and it doesn't really try.  So I'd say the only thing you're doing "wrong" is trying to use a feature that doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't know how desperately you need the compiler to understand the logic here, but if you really want to see this, you can refactor to something like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wj1lMW) which expresses what you're doing as a generic *indexed access*, which the compiler is much better at following.  Let me know if you want to see this written up in an answer (along with the links above).  Pls mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me if you reply

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript doesn't do any magic (yet) with generically typed parameters, so the type of `getIndex ? 1 : ''` is `string | number`, not `B extends true ? number : string`. This doesn't match with the return type of the function, so you get an error.

An alternative is to use overloads:

```
function handleTab(getIndex?: false): string
function handleTab(getIndex: true): number;
function handleTab(getIndex?: boolean): string | number;
function handleTab(getIndex?: boolean): string | number {
    return getIndex ? 1 : '';
}
```

There is an extra `handleTab(getIndex?: boolean)` so it still works correctly when you pass something of type `boolean`.

Another way using overloads is to just move the signature into one:

```
function handleTab<B extends boolean = false>(getIndex?: B): B extends true ? number : string;
function handleTab(getIndex?: boolean): string | number {
    return getIndex ? 1 : '';
}
```

However, both these examples do not check if the returned expression actually matches the overloads. You could return just `1` and it wouldn't complain.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJXBkN)

Comment: It might be useful to mention the caveat that overload implementations are checked loosely, so if you change the body to `return getIndex ? "" : 1` the compiler will not catch the mistake.  That is, this trades a false positive error (incompleteness) for a potential false negative lack-of-error (unsoundness).

Comment: This works great, thank you! Also good to know jcalz
TIL overloads